# dynamic id ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to set a dynamic id to my div within my ng-repeat. Let me show an example.

```
<div id="$index" ng-repeat="repeat in results.myJsonResults">
    <div id="$index" ng-click="saveID($index)" ng-repeat="subRepeat in results.myJsonResults.subresults">
</div>
```

My problem is, when I click on my child div, I want to get my parent id name, but looks like angular doesn't set the ID properly to the div. Is it possible to set a dynamic ID in this concept?

PS: I tried, in the past, create a counter method on my controller and set an index, but it turns out that angular only recognizes the last value of this ID instead.

Comment: you can't repeat ID in  page, which you are doing. Why do you even need an ID?

Answer (score 73):

To answer your question, try this:

```
<div id="{{$index}}" ...>
```

While the above should work, this might be not what you want really (!). Please note that this is rather rare with AngularJS to manipulate elements by referring those by id.

You should focus on your model, declarative describe UI and let AngularJS do the rest without doing low-level DOM manipulations "by hand".

Comment: Do you have some good example of the same behavior in a good manner?

Comment: @marceloduende You would have to explain first what you are trying to do, functionally speaking... A working plunk would be ideal.

Comment: Agreed. Needing to set an id in a repeater is definitely a code smell. I would assume you are going to use jquery for some reason, and if that's correct, then you should write `directive`s for that

Comment: I think what the guys are trying to say is...unlike with jQuery, you don't need to use IDs to get a value. Normally you'd use ng-model to bind to a $scope variable. Because the binding is two ways, you'd have access to that variable at any point, including when you'd want to save or update it from within the controller.

Comment: @Sharondio Actually I suspect that the use-case here is to select an "active" div - whatever active can mean - so I'm not sure ngModel will be involved. Anyway, impossible to tell without more info from the question's author.

Comment: sometimes third party libraries require id strings and in this case we need unique id's

Comment: The real use case for this is because you want good html with labels for your controls so you need them to have an id to go in the for attribute.

Comment: A good example would be using 'label' elements with 'for' attribute and 'input' element with 'id' attribute in a 'ng-repeat'. You need 'id's in that case.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource $index will help if the ng-repeat is used only once in a given template. But if this is a template of a directive and I am using this directive more than once in the same page, then the set of elements from the directive have the same set of ids. The solution I am using is generating a random number, set in scope and use in "id" and "label"

Answer (score 35):

A use case I can think of is associating `<label>` elements with their respective `<input>` elements, as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/YqUAp/

Applied there is [a pkozlowski.opensource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301855/2770309)'s method

```
<label for="{{ 'textField-' + $index }}">Option {{ $index }}</label>
<input type="text" id="{{ 'textField-' + $index }}" ng-model="field"/>
```

Though I'm unsure if this is the most effective method. (Even if only for readability)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work (specifically for select elements with ng-options anyways) for me in angular 1.2rc3

Comment: I do exactly this for the same reason.
<label for="state-{{$index}}">New</label>
<input id="state-{{$index}}" type="radio" ng-model="item.State" value="new" name="state-{{$index}}" />

Answer (score 8):

```
<div id="{{$index}}" ...>
```

Works well, but you can also put a dynamic id with the field repeated if - for instance - subRepeat would have an id field.
That would be:

```
<div id="subRepeat{{subRepeat.id}}" ...>
```

That will put ids like subRepeat1, subRepeat2, ... on your repeated div

Answer (score 1):

you need to hold the index in your objects

```
results = { myJsonResults : [ 
    { name: "abc", id: 1, subResults: [
                               { subName: "123", id: 1 },
                               { subName: "456", id: 2 }] }
    { name: "xyz", id: 2, subResults: [
                               { subName: "789", id: 1 },
                               { subName: "098", id: 2 }] }
                            ] };
```

Also your repeat refers to results, which disconnects them, instead use thisResult:

```
<div id="thisResult.id" ng-repeat="thisResult in results.myJsonResults">
    {{ thisResult.name }}
    <div id="subResult.id" ng-click="saveID(subResult.id)" ng-repeat="subResult in thisResult.subResults"> {{ subResult.subName }} </div>
</div>
```