# Angularjs ng-repeat index

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can get ng-repeat current record index? I am trying to give each record div an id equal to the record index example:

```
 <div id="1"> 
 <div id="2"> 
 <div id="3">
```

Any example is highly apreciated.

The ng-repeat i am using is as follows:

```
      <div ng-repeat="rows in clients.Result">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic id ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301746/dynamic-id-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $index with evaluation curls:

```
<div id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="rows in clients.Result">
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Ul3r5D58zukskpIScF7?p=preview)

Comment: @mchan Make sure that you understand that index starts at 0, so if you want `1`, `2`, `3` like your demo than you can just have `id="{{ $index + 1 }}"`. Also note that running filters on the repeater will change the index to reflect the visible list.

Comment: Your example looks good, just adding a couple side notes for the OP. I have already given you a +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

`$index` contains the current index. So you can use it inside your `ng-repeat` like `{{$index}}`.

All these variables are documented at the very top of the [`ng-repeat` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).