# Increment input ID Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to increment my input ID while using ng-repeat and I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
<div ng-repeat="d in index">

<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="" id="{{d}}" ng-model="{{d}}"/>

</div>
```

Do you have any ideas about how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can track by $index your ng-repeat

```
div ng-repeat="d in index track by $index"
  input type="checkbox" name="name" value="" id="{{$index}}" ng-model="{{d}}"/
/div
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<div ng-repeat="d in index track by $index">

<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="" id="{{$index}}" ng-model="d"/>

</div>
```

[dynamic id ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301746/dynamic-id-ng-repeat)

Comment: thanks for your help , but it doesn't work , to explain what I want to do is to  make this dynamic to make many input's from a JSON file :

 <div class="class1">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="check2" ng-model="check2" ng-change="getChecked2()">
                                    <label for="check2" class="check"></label>
                                    <label for="check2">{{VarServices[0].DesignationFR}} {{VarServices[0].Prix}} $ </label>
                                </div>

Comment: if you have differnet model for every checkbox so you can get value by different models